# How do I sum columns of data across a spreadsheet into a column on a separate sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Example:  On one spreadsheet, I have columns and rows of data (A1 through G10).  On a separate spreadsheet, I am trying to get the sum of each of the columns from the first into a column running down on the second spreadsheet.

Comment: Is there any way to copy the formula into the cells running down without having to type the formula into every cell?

Comment: Enter the first formula and swipe to the right. Enter Ctrl+R and Excel will fill the other cells adjusting the columns A->G. Then drag the cells down into place.

Answer (score 4):

On the second sheet enter in the `SUM` formula. After you type the open paren you can manually enter the range or use the mouse. To use the mouse select Sheet1 and swipe the cells you want summed. Then type the close paren. You should have a formula like this:

```
=SUM(Sheet1!A1:A10)
```

You can repeat the same process for the other cells. For example:

```
=SUM(Sheet1!B1:B10)
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to get a total of the entire column, no matter how many rows of data there are, use the following formula in the cell you want the total on the second sheet.

`=SUM(Sheet1!A:A)`

`Sheet1` represents the sheet where the data is at. If your sheet is named something different you will need to change this to match that.

`A:A` tells Excel you want all the data in column A. This will also include any data added after you've created the formula reference to the column. Using a range (A1:A10) limits the results to the range and will not SUM any added data outside the range.

Repeat this formula in each cell you want the total for a column and change the `A:A` to the column you want a total from (B:B, C:C, D:D, etc.)

Comment: Good point. The downside of course would be to include data in a sum that you don't want.

Comment: The OP did say they wanted it "sum of each of the columns from the first into a column running down". The great thing about Excel is there are often many ways to do the same thing, giving the user options.

Comment: And the OP cited a specific range "A1 through G10" so who can say. In agreement about the many different ways to do things in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

On Sheet2 use this formula and copy down to occupy seven rows.

```
=SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$G$10,0,ROW(A1)))
```

This formula does not require any moving or editing of cells or creating the sum manually for each result cell.